# PHP - How to explode a string which is the value of a key in assossiative array

Tags: wordpress, explode

I have a entered by the user as the VALUE of the KEY id. Now what I want here is to explode it and save the result in a variable called $items. Here is my code.

```
function featured_deal ($atts, $content){
extract( shortcode_atts(array(
    'icon' => '',
    'title' => '',
    'small_title' => '',
    'deal_categories' => '',
    'deal_locations' => '',
    'deal_stores' => '',
    'deals_number' => '3',
    'deals_orderby' => 'offer_expire',
    'deals_order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => '',
    'order' => '',
    'id' => '',

),$atts ));

$items = explode(',',  $id);


ob_start();
include (locate_template('includes/box-elements/deals.php'));
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $content;
}

add_shortcode('fd','featured_deal' );
```

My question is how to refer the KEY 'id' in explode function.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Let's `var_dump($items);`

Comment: Ok I try to make my question clear. Usually we explode a string that is stored inside a variable. Right? But I want to explode a string that is stored as a VALUE of the KEY 'id'. How to do this I mean do I have to write in explode() methode?

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP comment:

Nothing special, you just need to reference to that key in your array:

```
$data = [
    'akey' => 'avalue',
    'someother' => 'otherval',
    'id' => '2,3,5,87,47'
];
$items = explode(',', $data['id']); //<!-- Here you go
var_dump($items);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => string '87' (length=2)
  4 => string '47' (length=2)
```